# Fourier series for a half-wave rectifier

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series

I have to make a problem very similair to the attached example, I tried working it through but I am stuck when the integral for $a_n$ is solved, I dont get where the highlighted +1 comes from.
If I fill in the boundaries all $w$ cancel and I don't have this +1

[image: The example]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from evaluating the integral at $t = 0$

\begin{eqnarray}
a_n &=& \frac{\omega E}{2\pi}\left[-\frac{\cos(1 + n)\omega t}{(1 + n)\omega} -\frac{\cos(1 - n)\omega t}{(1 - n)\omega}\right]_0^{\pi/\omega}\\
&=& \frac{E}{2\pi}\left[ -\frac{\cos(1 + n)\pi}{(1 + n)} +\color{red}{\frac{\cos(1 + n)0}{(1 + n)}}-\frac{\cos(1 - n)\pi}{(1 - n)} +\color{red}{\frac{\cos(1 - n)0}{(1 - n)}}\right] \\
&=& \frac{E}{2\pi}\left[ -\frac{\cos(1 + n)\pi + \color{red}{1}}{(1 + n)} -\frac{\cos(1 - n)\pi+\color{red}{1}}{(1 - n)} \right]
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Of course! I totally forgot about that, thanks :)